# How to show what variables are being added in this recursive function

Tags: javascript, arrays

This function takes an array: `var data = [5,10,28,50,56,280];` and checks to see if it can combine any of the indexes together to create a number larger than a variable: `30` in this case. The function works perfectly but I want it to show the indexes it is adding to get its results. In this case 33 would show `28 + 5`.

```js
var findLowest = function(ary, limit) {
    if (limit < ary[0]) return ary[0];

    // If there's a number in our ary that's higher than the limit,
    // this is the initial benchmark
    var bestCandidate = Infinity,
        maxIndex = ary.findIndex(v => v > limit);

    if (maxIndex !== -1) {
        bestCandidate = ary[maxIndex] - limit;
        ary = ary.slice(0, maxIndex);
    }

    // Calculate remainders, call this method recursively for all remainders
    var diffs = ary.map(v => limit % v);

    var finalDiffs = diffs.map(v => findLowest(ary, v) - v);
    
    return limit + Math.min(bestCandidate, finalDiffs.sort()[0]);
    
};

var prepareData = function(ary) {
    return ary
        // Remove duplicates of nrs in array
        .reduce((res, v) => {
            var needed = !res.length || res.every(r => v % r);
            return needed ? res.concat(v) : res;
        }, [])

        // Generate each combination (length * length - 1)
        .reduce((res, v, i, all) => {
            return res.concat(v).concat(all.slice(i + 1).map(v2 => v + v2));
        }, [])
        
        // Sort lowest first
        .sort((a, b) => a - b);
}

var data = [5,10,28,50,56,280];
var testCases = [
    [data, 30, 0], //<----30 is being tested against the array
];

testCases.forEach(tc => {
    var prep = prepareData(tc[0]);
    var result = findLowest(prep, tc[1]);

    if (result !== tc[2]) {
      document.write("Result: ", result);
    }
});
```

Comment: So return not a scalar value but a structure with operands instead?

Comment: @zerkms Yes. I'm having trouble breaking this apart and seeing how to do that.

Comment: `return {left: op1, right: op2}`?

Comment: @zerkms Where are you implementing

Comment: In the `findLowest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your logic, the indexes it is adding to get its result is always going to be the first and last elements of the sliced array.

`console.log(ary[0] + ',' + ary[finalDiffs.length -1])`

before you return `findLowest`.

Comment: It works for `30` but does;t seem to show the sums for higher numbers. However you got closer than me.